# Can I take Backup of my database in mongodb atlas (free version)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-backups

I am using a free version of mongoDB atlas database.
I want to take a backup of my database.
Whatever resources I found. they are suggesting that to take a backup I need to have a paid version.

Is there any way by which I can take a backup.
Manual backup will also do for me.

Comment: I think you can use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongoexport/) or [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongodump/) and make a manual backup.